# Godot delta is acting very weird

Tags: godot, delta, gdscript

So I am working on a game with Godot. It is an infinite runner, so I need to spawn in a platform ahead of the player every few seconds. The timer node was confusing, so I just made a variable and added delta to it in _process. However, It didn't seem to work. Then I tried assigning a variable to delta and then printing delta and the variable, like this:

```
print(delta)
de = delta
print(de)
```

then I get an output like this:

0.16667
0
0.16667
0

which signifies that delta isn't being added to a variable. What can I do to try and fix this and why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wanted this:

```
var timer = 0.0

func _process(delta):
    timer += delta
    if timer > 1.0: # after one second passed
        # reset the timer and do something here
        timer = 0.0
```